# How to grep (or find) on cPanel?

Tags: search, deployment, cpanel, file-manager

How can I search for a specific string (function name or a variable name) in my files which are in various directories under cPanel file manager?

I have been using a library directory and functions on that directory are used in various apps and pages. Now, I am in a situation to change something in the library file, for which I need to know the impact on files which use this library file functions.

How to search / find / grep through the files hosted?

Comment: I don't think you can through a cpanel (maybe a cron job set to run only once), but if you ssh to a server you can do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can understand the frustration when you don't have access to SSH. Below is a simple PHP script that you save in a file in the root folder from where you want to start your search. For example, I wanted to find all files that have the HEX color code string `ecebeb` under the `../public_html` (or the `www`) folder. Retracing the steps here.

1. Login to yourdomain/cpanel
2. Go to File Manager - elect to go to `www/public_html`
3. Create new file with `.php` extension - I created `ecebeb.php` - then edit it.
4. Copy below 6 lines script, paste it in the `ecebeb.php` edit window and save the file.

   `<?php`
   `$command = "grep -ri 'ecebeb' ./*";`
   `$output = shell_exec($command);`
   `echo "$output";`
   `echo "Grep job over.";`
   `?>`
5. Now, open a new browser tab/window and browse to the URL like `yourdomain/ecebeb.php`

Comment: You will be happy to know that Cpanel has now added a search facility in the File Manager.

Comment: @Sri Unfortunately it doesn't search within files, it only looks for file *names*.

Comment: I've used this code several times. Thank you @Sri. However, I'm trying to use it on a significantly larger website now, and I've been unsuccessful. In fact, the page just appears to be loading for a long period of time. Then, it comes back and says page could not be found. Does this code not work on large websites?

Comment: I add pre to make it readable

Comment: This is not works for me. I prefer to download all files and then search in them with note pad ++ and it works.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it’s impossible.  You must write a PHP/Perl/Python/whatever script and run it on your server to get the list of files and grep through it.